# KVM guest can't connect to itself after DNAT

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, nat, ip-routing, dnat

## Network Description

Virtual hosting environment (KVM):

Guest:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l
Linux ari 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Host:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
Linux host 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Network:

```
          eth0 |----------| virbr63                    eth0 |----------|
---------------|   HOST   |---------------------------------|  ari     |
  11.22.33.44  |----------| 192.168.63.1       192.168.63.2 |----------|
```

- `11.22.33.44` is the public IP address
- `ari` is a virtual machine (guest)
- `HOST` is a physical machine (virtual machine host)
- `eth0` is a physical network card in `HOST`
- `virbr63` is a virtual network adapter

There is an iptables rule on HOST:

```
-I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 11.22.33.44 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.63.2:8888
```

Let's say `mydomain.com` resolves to 11.22.33.44.
ari is serving all the HTTP requests incoming on 11.22.33.44.
Curl-ing `mydomain.com` works from anywhere on the Internet.

## Problem

When I try to access `mydomain.com` through HTTP from `ari`, it does not work (curl hangs).

This is what the unsuccessful curl attempt looks like in tcpdump (on the host):

```
host$ sudo tcpdump -i virbr63 port 8888
22:03:15.541155 IP 192.168.63.2.42740 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [S], seq 786111635, win 14600, options [mss1460,sackOK,TS val 1662005624 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
22:03:15.541173 IP 192.168.63.2.42740 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [S], seq 786111635, win 14600, options [mss1460,sackOK,TS val 1662005624 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
```

This keeps repeating every few seconds.

This is what a successful curl attempt (from outside) looks like in tcpdump (on the host):

```
host$ sudo tcpdump -i virbr63 port 8888
21:59:10.924031 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [S], seq 2881442181, win 29200, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 4022859071 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:59:10.924339 IP 192.168.63.2.8888 > external.xxx.47812: Flags [S.], seq 1044842547, ack 2881442182, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1661944471 ecr 4022859071,nop,wscale 5], length 0
21:59:10.968371 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4022859117 ecr 1661944471], length 0
21:59:10.976415 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [P.], seq 1:72, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4022859117 ecr 1661944471], length 71
21:59:10.976683 IP 192.168.63.2.8888 > external.xxx.47812: Flags [.], ack 72, win 453, options [nop,nop,TS val 1661944484 ecr 4022859117], length 0
21:59:10.977985 IP 192.168.63.2.8888 > external.xxx.47812: Flags [P.], seq 1:909, ack 72, win 453, options [nop,nop,TS val 1661944484 ecr 4022859117], length 908
21:59:11.025271 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [.], ack 909, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 4022859175 ecr 1661944484], length 0
21:59:11.030033 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [F.], seq 72, ack 909, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 4022859175 ecr 1661944484], length 0
21:59:11.030375 IP 192.168.63.2.8888 > external.xxx.47812: Flags [F.], seq 909, ack 73, win 453, options [nop,nop,TS val 1661944497 ecr 4022859175], length 0
21:59:11.075205 IP external.xxx.47812 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [.], ack 910, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 4022859223 ecr 1661944497], length 0
```

- `external.xxx` is the reverse DNS of the IP address that is making the request

This is a monitoring setup, so I'm looking for a solution with as few changes on `host` as possible. Preferably no changes on host, just convincing `ari` (guest) to accept the packets and route the responses through the network.

## Non-Solutions

### What Doesn't Solve My Problem

#### Access ari:8888 directly

This does not help, because this is a monitoring setup and the whole purpose is to test if 11.22.33.44:80 works.

#### Access from a different guest (virtual machine)

It does work (also from the same network, `192.168.63.0/24`), but it doesn't solve the problem.

### What I've Tried and Doesn't Work

#### Similar Questions

I've looked at the following questions and the answers:

[DNAT from localhost (127.0.0.1)](https://serverfault.com/questions/551487/dnat-from-localhost-127-0-0-1)

[KVM guest cannot connect to host, but works vice versa](https://serverfault.com/questions/742359/kvm-guest-cannot-connect-to-host-but-works-vice-versa)

#### accept_local

```
ari$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_local=1
```

It doesn't solve the problem, doesn't change the tcpdump output.

#### route_localnet

```
ari$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

It doesn't solve the problem, doesn't change the tcpdump output.

#### rp_filter

```
ari$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
```

It doesn't solve the problem, doesn't change the tcpdump output.

#### Second (Virtual) Network Interface on `ari`

I've tried adding a second network interface `eth0:1` with IP address `192.168.63.200`. Accessing `192.168.63.2:8888` from `192.168.63.200` fails the same way:

```
17:42:08.746328 IP 192.168.63.200.41676 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [S], seq 3211292625, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1744488483 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
17:42:08.746351 IP 192.168.63.200.41676 > 192.168.63.2.8888: Flags [S], seq 3211292625, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1744488483 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
```

#### EDIT: Similar Solution

After kupson's answer I've found a very similar solution here:

http://idallen.com/dnat.txt (search for "Many clients - too much SNAT"). It has:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/24 -d 172.16.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT  -j SNAT --to 172.16.0.254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use SNAT on the HOST to change the source address of packets and forward them back to "ari" VM. It's not the most performant solution but it's simple and good enough for many setups.

```
# fixup chain
iptables -t nat -N fixup-snat
iptables -t nat -A fixup-snat -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j MASQUERADE

# please select proper network ranges and NIC names below
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.63.0/24 -d 192.168.63.0/24 -o virbr63 -j fixup-snat
```

You can merge this into single `iptables` rule, I prefer separate chain for clarity.

You should also disable processing packets by iptables on the bridge interface:

```
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

To make those survive reboot on Debian systems please edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file or create new file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then because of the "-s 192.168.63.0/24" it will only MASQUERADE for requests originating from 192.168.63.0/24 and the traffic originating from outside (Internet) will hit ari as before (this is good).

As it works from other machines on 192.168.63.0/24 , I can probably change it to "-s 192.168.63.2". Right?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. It's just my preference to setup it on whole network. Please note that there is additional requirement there -- packets needs to be DNAT-ed (--ctstate DNAT) so it won't trigger on normal traffic from HOST to "ari".

Comment: Thanks, @kupson. I've tried it. Interestingly, it only works when tcpdump is running on the host! I've added the details to the original question.

Comment: What's the output of `sysctl -a | grep bridge-nf` command?

Comment: ari:empty. Host:

`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged = 0`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged = 0`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-pass-vlan-input-dev = 0`

Comment: Please try to disable `bridge-nf-call-*` - processing packets by iptables rules twice (+1 on the bridge interface) can be tricky:
`sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0`
`sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0`
`sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0`

Comment: Yes, doing the 3 sysctl settings solves the problem. When I tcpdump it, there are no duplicate packets, and it works fine without a tcpdump.
I clean up my question and accept your answer. Can you please edit your answer and add the 3 sysctls?
Thank you very much, @kupson!